# Connecting to mysql on a vagrant box from phpmysql on my local machine

Tags: phpmyadmin, vagrant

I have phpmysql running locally and am wanting to connect to an instance of MySQL that is installed and running on the same machine. Here are the relevant config files:

#vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 33060
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

#phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$j++;
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['host'] = '192.168.33.10:8080'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['port'] = '33060'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['user'] = 'root';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['password'] = 'password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
```

I've also set MySQL on the vagrant box to allow for remote connections with this:

`bind-address            = 0.0.0.0` in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

I when I try and connect from phpmyadmin I'm seeing the error "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '10.0.2.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had multiple issues going on. Here is the configuration I have now:

#vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 33060
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

#phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$j++;
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['port'] = '33060'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['user'] = 'root';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['password'] = 'password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$j]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
```

In addition to this I had to run this command on MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```